# Microsoft Tutorial problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Microsoft Tutorial problems

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Hello, Im not sure if this is the right forum for this question, but ill try here!

I am working through this tutorial; http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

But as mentioned in the bottom comments, my database isn't created when i run add-migration and update-database in the Package Manager Console..

It seems like its a common problem, my web.config sql string;

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ContosoUniversityModelBinding2-20140407112726.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ContosoUniversityModelBinding2-20140407112726;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Do you have any idea why my .mdf is not created, as it works for the author of the tutorial? :)

The error is

*Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details*

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details, I have updated my question

Comment: did you check your EntityValidationErrors?  It usually means that one or more of your entity field values is not valid (e.g : string length, required field etc.)